# Why doesn't this css remove text-decoration?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a post that has a title.  I select like so =>

```
<h4><strong><%= link_to post.title, post, :class => "post-title" 
%></strong></h4>
```

I want to take away the text-decoration it gets by default form being a link.  So i have this in my posts css =>

```
.post-title  {
text-decoration: none;
 }
```

I have tried selecting the text in all kinds of different ways and I just can't get that text-decoration to go away..

the html output is just the title of the post with standard text-decoration (blue color with an underline)

I checked safari web inspector and none of my rules were overridden.

Comment: what's the html output

Comment: Have you checked via web inspector this element to check whether this css rule is being overridden by the other rule? 
Btw try `a.post-title  {
text-decoration: none;
 }`

Comment: You will get better help if you post the HTML that is generated, instead of the back-end code. Then remove the tags that aren't relevent to Css problems.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I gave the erb an id of post-title and did the following in my css to select it:

```
a#post-title {
    text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try...

```
a.post-title {text-decoration: none;}
```

There's not enough [CSS specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) in your selector.

There will be a **browser or reset stylesheet** applying the text decoration to anchor elements and **your** stylesheet applying it to anything with a class of 'post-title'. At the moment the anchor style is *winning*.

Example

```
a {text-decoration: underline} //Browser CSS
.post-title {text-decoration: none} //Your CSS
```

Both of those apply to...

```
a.post-title
```

Comment: Author declarations have more [importance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) than user agent declarations. And even if they had the same importance, a class selector has more [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than a type selector.

Comment: True but If it's some kind of framework reset then it may be applied to a wrapper class. In which case the OP just needs to increase the specificity. See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gejxbt8n/